# Javascript: Submit form by clicking on any anchor tag within a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and many links:

```
<form action="/a">
<input type=text name=somedata>
<input type=submit>

<a href="/b">my first link</a>
<a href="/c">link</a>
<a href="/d">link</a>
<a href="/e">link</a>
</form>
```

If the user presses submit, the form should be submitted to /a, as usual (so no change).

But when the user clicks on /b, instead of scrapping somedata and sending a GET-request to /b, I want to send a POST request to /b just as if the form was `<form action=/b>`.

Is it possible to do this automatically with all hypertext anchors on the page, so that it not only works with /b, but also /c, /d and /e?

Both pure Javascript and jQuery are acceptable.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: No, I don't know how to add an onClick-event on all anchors via Javascript

Comment: If you are using jQuery you can use the `el.on("click", () => doFun(); )` and if plan old JS will be `el.addEventListener("click", () => doFun(); )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `action` of the form to the `href` of the `<a>` selected and then submit form

```
$('form a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('form').attr('action', this.href ).submit();
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it does indeed go to the href from the anchor (so the submit seems to work), but all form-data is lost. (At least it does not show up in $_REQUEST)

Comment: No reason it shouldn't work...the only thing that changes is the action. Did you set method on the form?

Comment: phpinfo() has shown me the problem: REQUEST_METHOD  GET - But I use: `<form name=form action="/Test" method=post>`

Comment: Seems like the JS doesn't get executed, I use simply `<script type="text/javascript">$('form a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('form').attr('action', this.href ).submit();
});</script>`

Comment: Is that script tag after the form tag? If not you need a ready handler http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

```js
var form = document.querySelector("form");
var allA = document.querySelectorAll("a");

allA.forEach(function(el){
  
  el.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    form.action = this.href;
    console.log("Form action is been change to => " + this.href)
    form.submit();
    e.preventDefault();        
  });
  
});

form.addEventListener("submit",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("The form has been submit");
});
```

```html
<form action="/a">
<input type=text name=somedata>
<input type=submit>

<a href="/b">my first link</a>
<a href="/c">link</a>
<a href="/d">link</a>
<a href="/e">link</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var form = document.querySelector("form");
var allA = document.querySelectorAll("a");

allA.forEach(function(el){
  
  el.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    form.submit();
    e.preventDefault();        
  });
  
});

form.addEventListener("submit",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("The form has been submit");
});
```

```html
<form action="/a">
<input type=text name=somedata>
<input type=submit>

<a href="/b">my first link</a>
<a href="/c">link</a>
<a href="/d">link</a>
<a href="/e">link</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast ;-) , but this would still submit everything to /a, please also change the action in form to the href from a, so I can accept your answer

Comment: Oh sorry are you meaning if click on `a` then it will be submitting to action `/b`?

Comment: I help you to update the code and post a new answer,hope that will help you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remove submit button.

```
$("#formId a").click(function(){
   var currentHref = $(this).attr("href");
   $("#formId").attr("action",currentHref);
   $("#formId").submit();
});
```